# I'm getting "There was an error while overriding '' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined' error in Azure Devops

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm getting below error when trying to deploy Azure Alerts for storage account using ARM templets (From azure devops pipeline)

Error
The detected encoding for file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Alerts_parameters.json' is 'utf-8'
There was an error while overriding '' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details.

##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details.

Pipeline Step and Variable declaration.

```
variables:
- name: subscriptionId
  value: 'XXXX'
- name: azureResourceManagerConnection
  value: 'Visual Studio Professional Subscription(XXXX)'
- name: resourceGroupName
  value: 'AB-RG-PP-TEST'
- name: storageAccounts_externalid
  value: '/subscriptions/$(subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(resourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/st${{ lower(parameters.Project) }}${{ lower(parameters.ENV) }}'
- name: actiongroups_application_insights_smart_detection_externalid
  value: '/subscriptions/$(subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(resourceGroupName)/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/application insights smart detection'

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  name: 'Alert_Deployment'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: $(azureResourceManagerConnection)
    subscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'Alerts.json'
    csmParametersFile: 'Alerts_parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    overrideParameters: -storageAccounts_externalid ${{ variables.storageAccounts_externalid }} -actiongroups_application_insights_smart_detection_externalid  ${{ variables.actiongroups_application_insights_smart_detection_externalid }} -metricAlerts_AZURE_INFRASTUCTURE_Isssues_name AZURE INFRASTUCTURE Isssues
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `'/home/vsts/work/1/s/Alerts_parameters.json' is 'utf-8' There was an error while overriding '' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined'`,
it is suggested that you could check the `Alerts_parameters.json` for the missing parameter value `property 'type' of undefined'`.

Or you could share the parameter.json file with us for reference

Comment: I have found out that we cannot pass "/" as overrideParameters. I'm working on workaround at the moment.

Comment: @anuruddhas hi could you share the latest status of you issue or share your workaound or solution as an answer to help more developers?

Comment: Sure, I will create a proper guide and update

Comment: @anuruddhas ， thx for your feedback, you could look into this [wiki reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and post an answer